# Using Automapper to map a service result to a view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, domain-driven-design, automapper

I am trying to map a service result to a specific view model. I have an Entity called Category which contains an Id and a Name. I expose this via a repository, ICategoryRepository. I have a service IInfrastructureService that uses the category repository to GetAllCategories. GetAllCategories returns an IList. In my MVC project. I have a controller called NavigationController. This controller needs to make a call to the service to GetAllCategories. I would like to map this result into a structure like this:

```
public class CategoryViewModel {
    public Guid CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryMenuViewModel {
    public IList<CategoryViewModel> Categories { get; set; }
    public CategoryViewModel SelectedCategory { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to use Automapper to do this. In my Application_Start() I create the maps:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Category, CategoryViewModel>();
```

Then in my controller:

```
public ViewResult CategoryMenu()
{
    CategoryMenuViewModel viewModel = new CategoryMenuViewModel();
    Mapper.CreateMap<Category, CategoryViewModel>();
    viewModel.Categories = Mapper.Map<IList<Category>, IList<CategoryViewModel>>(_infrastructureService.GetAllCategories());
    return View(viewModel);
}
```

This is giving me this exception: Duplicate type name within an assembly.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any help or guidance would rock!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are you calling `Mapper.CreateMap` inside your controller? This should be called only once for the entire lifetime of the AppDomain, ideally in `Application_Start`. Inside the controllers you call the `Mapper.Map` method only.

The reason you are getting the exception is because you have already defined a mapping (.CreateMap) between the Category and CategoryViewModel in your Application_Start. So:

```
public ViewResult CategoryMenu()
{
    var categories = _infrastructureService.GetAllCategories();
    CategoryMenuViewModel viewModel = new CategoryMenuViewModel();
    viewModel.Categories = Mapper.Map<IList<Category>, IList<CategoryViewModel>>(categories);
    return View(viewModel);
}
```